# Unable to configure @babel/core: .inherits must be a function, or undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm unable to build my project, constantly receiving a babel error:

```
  ERROR in ./src/index.js
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
    Error: [BABEL] C:\my-project\src\index.js: .inherits must be a function, or undefined
        at assertFunction (C:\my-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\option-assertions.js:140:11)
        at C:\my-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\plugins.js:63:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at validatePluginObject (C:\my-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\plugins.js:54:20)
        at C:\my-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:261:55
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at Function.<anonymous> (C:\my-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:16:3)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at step (C:\my-project\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
        at evaluateAsync (C:\my-project\node_modules\gensync\index.js:291:5)
        at Function.errback (C:\my-project\node_modules\gensync\index.js:113:7)
        at errback (C:\my-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:60:18)
        at async (C:\my-project\node_modules\gensync\index.js:188:31)
        at onFirstPause (C:\my-project\node_modules\gensync\index.js:216:13)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at cachedFunction (C:\my-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:58:46)
        at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
        at loadPluginDescriptor (C:\my-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:252:17)
        at loadPluginDescriptor.next (<anonymous>)
        at loadPluginDescriptors (C:\my-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:159:30)
        at loadPluginDescriptors.next (<anonymous>)
        at C:\my-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:187:21
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at loadFullConfig (C:\my-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:170:5)
        at loadFullConfig.next (<anonymous>)
        at Function.transform (C:\my-project\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transform.js:17:45)
        at transform.next (<anonymous>)
        at step (C:\my-project\node_modules\gensync\index.js:269:25)
        at C:\my-project\node_modules\gensync\index.js:273:13
        at async.call.result.err.err (C:\my-project\node_modules\gensync\index.js:223:11)
     @ multi ./src/main.less ./src/index.js my-project[1]
```

I'm using webpack 4.46.*

Here is my dependencies:

```
    "@babel/cli": "7.13.10",
    "@babel/core": "7.13.10",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.13.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.13.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.13.8",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.12.13",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.13.10",
```

Here is the problem:
** Error: [BABEL] C:\my-project\src\index.js: .inherits must be a function, or undefined**

I'have tried different versions of @babel plugins, nothing helps.

Here is my .babelrc:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [ "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true } ],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", { "corejs": 2} ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

Unfortunatelly, I can't share my webpack config.

Next code causes the error:

```js
class X {
  static propTypes = 10
}
```

So I believe it might be `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`.

Please help!

**UPDATE**

So, it works with next config:

```js
{

  "presets": [

    "@babel/preset-react"

  ],

  "plugins": [

    [ "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true } ],

    "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties",

    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",

  ]

}
```

However, I'm receiving next error on every `import` statement:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';

    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: Does the error change to a different one if you comment out `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` then?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I will let you know in Monday

Comment: You can always do a bit of a binary-search by commenting out stuff to see what is screwing things up. I'd also recommend deleting any lockfiles you have and installing all the deps to see if maybe something in your dependency try has gotten screwed up somehow.

Comment: Yes, I tried. I have commented seversl plugins and I thought I fixed it, but after I run jest tests I ended up with same error

Comment: If removing all the plugins still shows that error, then you must have an issue somewhere else. Are Jest and babel-jest fully up to date? Do you maybe have additional babel config somewhere else?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I made an update